# Does 不幸{ふこう} always carry a "stronger" idea than 悲{かな}しみ?

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

From jisho.org:

> ## **不幸{ふこう}**
>
> unhappiness; sorrow; misfortune; disaster; accident; death ([source](http://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%8D%E5%B9%B8))
>
> ---
>
> ## **悲{かな}しみ**
>
> sadness; sorrow; grief ([source](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%82%B2%E3%81%97%E3%81%BF))

After looking at this, it seems to me that although both words mean sadness, the presence of the other "more drastic" meanings in 不幸{ふこう} such as *disaster* and *death* contribute for the word 不幸{ふこう} to be interpreted as a stronger/deeper sadness. Am I correct? **Does the word 不幸{ふこう} always carry a heavier idea of sadness?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"不幸" is an event. There are various events of "不幸."

If you loose your partner or child, you must be shocked and deeply saddened "深く悲しむ（悲しみを覚える）" by the death of a loved one.

If you gamble away all your money, you might get to be mad about what happened to you, insted of "悲しむ(feel 悲しみ)."

"不幸" is an event, and "不幸" mostly make people feel sadness, but it depends on the nature of the event of "不幸(unhappiness)."

Comment: Thank you very much; sorry to take so long to give feedback to your answer.